# Need help in creating table in wordpress DB, using WPDB

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's my code. I keep receiving server 500 error when I'm trying to run it.

```
    //Insert DATA in db
global $wpdb;
$table_name='customers';

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
                                          ID int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                                          refnumber varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                                          primary key  (id)
                                          )$charset_collate;";


require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );


$wpdb->insert( $table_name,
                array( 'refnumber' => $customer['id']
                          )
              );
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have used a similar code almost like this one in the past with success.

UPDATE 1:

Okay so I turned wp debug on, nothing new displayed, I just get the usual error 500 page.

Tested my SQL syntax directly on the database. It works.

tested my php syntax with online tools, no errors.

Also corrected partially my code and what happens is that everything get executed without any errors, even error 500 doesn't appear anymore.

But! My database is not actually created, in the database of WP I just see the tables that I created manually.

I worked 4 hours on this today and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Also, tried to just insert the variable into the DB already created by me, no errors shown, but nothing is added.

I searched for other similar questions but it looks like I'm the only one with this problem.

Comment: Error 500 means that you have some sort of parsing error or syntax error. Check your error.log or add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your `wp-config.php` so that you will have better idea on where went wrong.

Comment: This code work fine in my site

Comment: thanks for your reply! I updated the question with my attempts of today, if you can give it a read I will be grateful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`dbDelta()` seems to be a bit strict in its requirements. I haven't worked with it much, but this page suggests that even an `int` needs a length: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table

I'm not sure if it matters that there is no space before `$charset_collate` in your code, but they also included a space before that in the example on that page.